# JQuery Tooltip Replacement is not showing first time

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in all my ejs files.

```
<font class="newicn" title="New">
```

Now I need to replace title commonly from .js file. Because I need to change 29 ejs files. Instead of changing title in an all .ejs files need to write script in js file. I wrote like this..

```
$('.newicn').live('mouseover', function ()
{
    $(this).attr("title","Newsfeed");
});
```

But firts time it is showing "New" only. First hover itself I need to show "Newsfeed". Anybody knows please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works... http://jsfiddle.net/7fxH3/

Comment: Just have `$('.newicn').attr("title","Newsfeed");` - Without the event handler.

Comment: $('.newicn').on('mouseover', function ()
{
    $(this).attr("title","Newsfeed");
});
this is not working for me. Live only working.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
$('.newicn').hover(function() {
   $(this).attr("title","Newsfeed");
});
```

You can also try

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.newicn').attr("title","Newsfeed");
});
```

Comment: I tried with all these things. All are working for second time only. First time still showing same.

Comment: put this after you main .js file which is calling the title in div else give the reference of that file to me.